# What "God's law" is Matthew Henry referring to?

Tags: mosaic-law, exodus, bible-commentary, matthew-henry

Part of Matthew Henry's commentary on Exodus 22 says:

> A man's house is his castle, and God's law, as well as man's, sets a guard upon it; he that assaults it does so at his peril.

What is he referring to as "God's law" in reference to setting a guard upon it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that this is a commentary on Exodus 22, which is dealing with issues relating to theft, this is likely on the specific "thou shalt not steal" commandment.

[The idea of property rights is found throughout Scripture](http://biblebaptistchurchcambridge.com/wordpress/?p=101), and taking someone's property is, in it's most basic form, theft.